# External ADC reference when using MATLAB support package for Arduino

Tags: analogread, adc, matlab, analog-sampling, analogreference

I am using the MATLAB support package for Arduino.

However, I need to configure the ADC reference to external. MATLAB documentation doesn't really explain how to do this?

Is there any way I can use the MATLAB support package and configure the Analog pins to use external ADC reference?

Answer (score -1):

> MATLAB documentation doesn't really explain how to do this?

it makes sense. read your arduino documentation instead.

> Is there any way I can use the MATLAB support package and configure the Analog pins to use external ADC reference?

absolutely.

Comment: Any more details on how to do this will be much appreciated. I am programming using only MATLAB and not writing a single line of C code using Arduino IDE. There is no mention of any wrapper function in the MATLAB documentation of its Arduino support package that lets the user configure the ADC reference to external.